# populate listbox with specific rows from an excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet named ("PPSBoarded") with 15 columns. I want to select rows based on similar values in column B and then display it in listbox on a VBA form. I tried this but it's not working:

```
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim FirstAddr As String

With Range("B1:B2")
    Set LastCell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
End With
Set FoundCell = Range("B1:B").Find(what:="EK261/GRU", after:=LastCell)

If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddr = FoundCell.Address
End If
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    Debug.Print FoundCell.Address
    Set FoundCell = Range("B1:B").FindNext(after:=FoundCell)
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddr Then
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop
Me.ListBox1.List = FirstAddr
```

Comment: What is that code doing? What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want it to display selected rows based on values in column (B) in excel sheet then display all the specific selected rows in a listbox

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
Dim arrLstBox()
Dim rng, FoundCell, tmpCell As Range
Dim i, j, numRows, lastColumn, lastRow As Long
Dim FirstAddress, searchFor, colWidth As String

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
numRow = 0

With rng

     lastRow = .Rows.Count
     lastColumn = .Columns.Count

End With

Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = lastColumn

For x = 1 To lastColumn
    If x = lastColumn Then
            colWidth = colWidth & "1,5cm"
            Exit For
    End If

    colWidth = colWidth & "1,5cm;"
Next x

    Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = colWidth

    searchFor = InputBox("Your word:")

    Set FoundCell = rng.Find(what:=searchFor)

    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then _
        FirstAddress = FoundCell.Address

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing

        Set FoundCell = rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then
            numRow = numRow + 1
            Exit Do
        ElseIf FoundCell.Row <> rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell).Row Then
            numRow = numRow + 1
        End If

    Loop

    ReDim arrLstBox(1 To numRow, 1 To lastColumn)

    Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing

        For i = 1 To numRow

            For j = 1 To lastColumn

                If Not IsEmpty(Cells(FoundCell.Row, j).Value) Then
                    arrLstBox(i, j) = Cells(FoundCell.Row, j).Value
                End If

                Set FoundCell = rng.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)

            Next j

            If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then _
                Exit For

        Next i

        If FoundCell.Address = FirstAddress Then _
                Exit Do

    Loop

    Me.ListBox1.List = arrLstBox()
```

Comment: thanks very much Irithyll. After running the code it stops at the first value in column B and displays $B$4 in the listbox. The first value is located in cell B4. but I want the code to display the entire rows that has the same value in the B column

Comment: You have to put the AddItem-Code between **End If** and **Loop**. But then it's neccessary to change the **0** to a variable (e.g. **i**) and increment this.

Comment: I seem not to be making any headway out Irithyll. if you can help me with a working End If and Looping code for this. pardon me am just about a month old with VBA.

Comment: I run the code but its still displaying the cell location ($B$4) in the listbox instead of the entire row details. This time the number of occurrences in the B column was ten so it displayed $B$4 ten times in the list box

Comment: Perfect its located all the instances along the column B, but can you please get it populate the list box with the entire row instead of cell location like $B$4 , &B$6 and so on

Comment: Btw - you are searching for **exact** values not **similar** ones...
I don't really know what you want ... you have values in column B, you want to search in every cell of this sheet for this value. Every cell-address has to be shown in this list. And I don't think an entire row isn't what you want because a cell in a row where this value is found would be just a number.

Or is it more like - searching for value "test". "test" is found e.g. in row 1, 4 and 7. You want to display the values of the whole rows 1, 4 and 7?

Comment: yes that is what I want, so for example if "test" is found in B4, B7 and B9 I want to display the entire rows 4, 7 and 9 in the list box

Comment: Now it's more like what you want. But you have to type the word you are searching for in an **InputBox**. Is it okay?

Comment: yes it is ok, its displaying all the raw values now. I really appreciate your time and expertise. Lastly is there any any reason why the details in the list box are displayed vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: Please try the new code. It will set the number of columns for the list to the highest column of the **UsedRange**. Each item of a row will be added to the list in a row, too. Empty cells won't be added. :) Have fun.

Comment: thank you, I run the code but there is an error (COULD NOT SET THE LIST PROPERTY, INVALID PROPERTY VALUE) on this line - Me.ListBox1.List(i, j) = Cells(FoundCell.Row, x).Value

Comment: hello Irithyll, am sure of the time difference but I hope you doing good. please debug the above for me I you get the time. thanks.

Comment: Yeah - you are right. This is a problem of ListBoxes - you can only set a maximum of 10 columns with my solution above. I changed it - now an array is filled with everything. :) Ah - I said sth. wrong, this method isn't searching for exact values, it's searching for "similar" entries, as you mentioned - sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks Irithyll, like you said I think I have to know what code properly works for what. I run the code which was pulling out the correct rows but all the columns couldn't display and also it gives me an error when it searches further says (Run-time error '9', subscript out of range) on this line of code = ReDim arrLstBox(1 To numRow, 1 To lastColumn). So what I did was I commented this line of code (    'Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = colWidth) and now I have the complete range of columns. But I cant figure out the error.

Comment: Could you make a picture of your data ot add the whole file? It's working for me in a field of data with 10 rows and 15 columns.

Comment: this populates my listbox with all sheet values.Private Sub cmdOPPS_Click()    Dim lbtarget As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim rngSource As Range
     'Set reference to the range of data to be filled
    Set rngSource = Worksheets("PPSBoarded").Range("A:L")
     'Fill the listbox
    Set lbtarget = Me.ListBox1
    With lbtarget
         'Determine number of columns
        .ColumnCount = 50
         'Set column widths
        .ColumnWidths = "60;70;190;40;90;90;70;80;50;60;90;120"
         'Insert the range of data supplied
        .List = rngSource.Cells.Value
    End With

Comment: ok how do i attach picture here please. otherwise i can send you the file if its ok

Comment: In my case the listbox was created manually in an UserForm. The code is working but you have to build this code correctly in... just upload a pic on a hoster and comment with the link. You can also edit your question I think.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the pic, just data. Try to create an UserForm and in it a ListBox manually. Then add the code to a button for example. It should work... The only thing you should change is the ColumnWidths :)

Comment: yes i already have all that working. which populates the listbox with all the data in the sheet without any conditions. the only issue i have now is selecting rows based on data in column B. which you have done for me but the error (Run-time error '9', subscript out of range) still persist.

Comment: on my way to work now will get off early tomorrow morning. hope i will complete this tomorrow. thanks for your time. appreciate it

Comment: Is it okay for you if you send me your file like it is now? Email: another.me@protonmail.com :x

Comment: good morning, i have sent the file please. thank you very much

Comment: Please try the code again - I addes just a line. "numRow = numRow + 1" - it's before the "Exit Do". Hope it's working now :)

Comment: Perfect Perfect Perfect, thanks thanks thanks, Its working now, and i also realized i can concatenate to look up for two words anywhere in the sheet. Thanks a lot Irithyll.

Comment: No problem :) Have fun ^ - ^

Comment: Hello how are you Irithyll. I have sent you an email please check if you have time. thanks

Comment: Hey there, I'm fine - it's not good to spam with comments. :) So now we are able to write via email ;)